# DLL Load Failure - Anaconda, MLWIC2

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, dll, anaconda

I'm running the MLWIC2 package for R which is supposed to classify camera trap photos for the first time. And at the same time, learning Anaconda/python for the first time. And I keep getting stopped at this error.

```
classify(path_prefix = "C:/Users/bird_/Desktop/C7_07162019",
data_info = "C:/Users/bird_/Desktop/image_labels.csv",
model_dir ="C:/Users/bird_/Desktop/MLWIC2_helper_files",
python_loc = "C:/Users/bird_/anaconda3/envs/enviro",
save_predictions = "model_predictions.txt",
architecture = 'resnet',
depth = 18,
top_n = 5,
batch_size = 128,
make_output = TRUE,
output_name = "MLWIC2_output.csv", num_cores = 16,
os="Windows",
num_classes=1000 )

Your data_info file exists: C:/Users/bird_/Desktop/image_labels.csv.
Your `path_prefix exists: C:/Users/bird_/Desktop/C7_07162019.
You are running on a Windows computer.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "run.py", line 14, in
import numpy as np
File "C:\Users\bird_\ANACON1\envs\enviro\lib\site-packages\numpy_init_.py", line 140, in
from . import distributor_init
File "C:\Users\bird\ANACON1\envs\enviro\lib\site-packages\numpy_distributor_init.py", line 34, in
from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
The classify function did not run properly.
```

I'm running it in an Anaconda environment with python 3.7, with numpy 1.16.0 (tried 1.16.4 too), and tensorflow 1.14.0.

I have reinstalled and updated Microsoft Visual C++, I have manually added msvcp71.dll into the system files and into the DLL file under anaconda3. I have tried adding to the PATH ~/Library/bin, I have uninstalled and reinstalled numpy. I am running out of options that already exist on the internet. I realize this might be an esoteric problem but the package repository hasn't been updated for a while (hence the older versions of packages). Can anyone help???

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

How about first activating the base environment?

```
conda activate
```

Comment: I've done that in conda. Do I have to do it in R? Thank you!